# How can I run "show partitions" from hadoop to load into a SAS table?

Tags: hadoop, hive, sas, impala

I want to run the following in hadoop, and put the results into a temp table in SAS.

```
show partitions schema_name.table_name
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Use jdbc to query Hive then make a new connection to your other table.